# Is there a way to prevent the recommended youtube videos using iframe?

Tags: iframe, youtube

Am displaying some youtubes video on my website using iFrame . 
Is there a way  to remove that recommended videos that appears at the videos end?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just wondering if you read the youTube API? Clearly stated: &rel=0

Comment: Thanks Leeish, a short and very helpfull answer.